# What are the 2 bytes in the beginning of u1.AddressOfData in the memory mapped IAT of PE files?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, portable-executable

So in order to parse the IAT table inside the memory of a PE process and get the names of imported functions, we have to iterate over functions of each module, and for each of them, use thunkData->u1.AddressOfData + 2 to get to the start of the Function name string (I don't want to start explaining what these pointers are because i assume anyone who knows the answer to this already knows this. and u1 is a predefined structure that Windows has and it always has AddressOfData in it)

so basically for every function inside the IAT, we have to use u1.AddressOfData + 2 to get the address of the start of the string, but i don't get what is the beginning 2 bytes of it? Microsoft documents don't explain this :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format

(look for Delay Import Name Table)

i tried debugging it and looking what the value in the beginning of them are, and they were stuff like 0x8600 and 0xe700, so usually 1 byte of data and one byte of 00

so what is this?

Comment: this is `IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME` - first `WORD` (2 bytes) is `Hint` (hint index in export table of module from which was import). really this is already obsolete. Hint almost always containing wrong value

Comment: So hint is the index of the export table of the module this function was loaded? and why does it always contain the wrong value, does it mean these 2 bytes are useless and never used?

Comment: yes, this bytes is useless. need look for current loader implementation - may be used, may be not. from where is *Hint* was get ? from *lib* which you use when build pe. really system images updated (how minimum when moving to next windows version), export table changed, indexes changes. on practice Hint usual wrong. however this not lead to error - this is only fast check, if miss - go to binary search correct index by name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in `IMAGE_THUNK_DATA`structure, if function address yet not resolved and function not snap by ordinal - `AddressOfData` is point to `PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME` (this is visible if look in *winnt.h* and/or *ntimage.h* )

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME {
    USHORT  Hint;
    CHAR   Name[1];
} IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME, *PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME;
```

the first 2 bytes before name - this is Hint index in *AddressOfNames* - exported names table (look for `IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY` ). this table of names sorted in alphabetical order for fast binary search function by name. Hint used for fast check, before drop into binary search. how it can used we can view in *wrk* src code

```
    //
    // Lookup Name in NameTable
    //

    NameTableBase = (PULONG)((PCHAR)DllBase + (ULONG)ExportDirectory->AddressOfNames);
    NameOrdinalTableBase = (PUSHORT)((PCHAR)DllBase + (ULONG)ExportDirectory->AddressOfNameOrdinals);

    //
    // Before dropping into binary search, see if
    // the hint index results in a successful
    // match. If the hint index is zero, then
    // drop into binary search.
    //

    HintIndex = ((PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)NameThunk->u1.AddressOfData)->Hint;
    if ((ULONG)HintIndex < ExportDirectory->NumberOfNames &&
        !strcmp((PSZ)((PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)NameThunk->u1.AddressOfData)->Name,
         (PSZ)((PCHAR)DllBase + NameTableBase[HintIndex]))) {
        OrdinalNumber = NameOrdinalTableBase[HintIndex];

    }
    else {

        //
        // Lookup the import name in the name table using a binary search.
        //
```

however this index usually can be valid only in system images. if we build image yourself - in best cast this Hint can be valid only for one windows version (we got Hint from *lib* file) - when new version windows created - usually new export api added, because table is sorted alphabetical - indexes is [can] changed

Comment: @Anders - you mean wrk code ? microsoft by self make this code open src

Comment: @Anders - i really don't know how is this all formal legal, may be you better know this. simply how i know - wrk was legal open source code, unlike win2000 src code, which is leak

Comment: I think you are supposed to have some special license, you can't just put it up on GitHub like that.

Comment: @Anders - so i need remove link but left code snippet ?

Comment: [WRK](https://web.archive.org/web/20081228035116/http://www.microsoft.com/resources/sharedsource/windowsacademic/researchkernelkit.mspx#http://www.microsoft.com/resources/sharedsource/licensing/basics/wrklicense.mspx): "...is available via MSDNAA Subscriber Downloads (accessible to administrators of participating departments) or via the Faculty Connection portal (sign-in required) to **eligible academic faculty or staff**." So, yes, I would remove the link. I don't know about the code.

Comment: I found this somewhere "As the WRK license agreement limits the number of lines of code that can be shown in one piece to 50 lines" but IANAL.

Comment: @Anders - it is interesting. i personally can not understand sense of this (if code sent  to public). you suggest removing the code from the answer?

Comment: at all wrk code became strong out date in many areas. will be very useful if such code partially will be open for win7 or better win10

Comment: You posted less than 50 lines so you are OK if that quote is correct. It does not matter how old the code or how irrelevant it is, you still have to follow the license.